# How to perform algorithm running time calculation?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I completely understand Big O notation but while trying to learn karatsuba algorithm the following statement confused me

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2)+ O(n)
=>T(n) = O(n^2)
```

How O(n^2) running time is derived from the first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `T(n) = aT(n / b) + O(n^c)`
where a=4, b=2, c=1

then
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1

```
T(n) = O(n^log2(4)) = O(n^2)
```